# python convert raw binary data to array of floats

Tags: python, arrays, binary, floating-point

I'm new to python but i need to get this project done in it. I'm using telnetlib to get some raw data from a device, and this is what the data looks like (this is only part of the output i get, the real one is about 10x bigger)

> \xc2\xb2\xdd\x0f\xc2\xb2x/\xc2\xb2\x08\xb2M\xcf\xc2\xb2\xc5S\xc2\xb2\xd6[\xc2\xb2qw\xc2\xb1\xafK\xc2\xb1n+\xc2\xb2?\x83\xc2\xb1\xe3\xb7\xc2\xb0\xe8\x87\xc2\xb0\xf1\x8f\xc2\xb1x\xbf\xc2\xb1\xcbO\xc2\xb1\x98\x93\xc2\xb1\xd4\xc3\xc2\xb1\xf7\x9f\xc2\xb1\xb3\x97\xc2\xb1\xe7;\xc2\xb2\x97\xcb\xc2\xb2\xd3\xf3\xc2\xb2f\x8b\xc2\xb1\xc6\xdb\xc2\xb1\xadC\xc2\xb1t\xcf\xc2\xb1\x9c\xdf\xc2\xb1\xb7\x1b\xc2\xb1\xa3\xc2\xb1\t_\xc2\xb1v\xc3\xc2\xb1\xeb

The documentation of the device says that this is

> raw data: binary. An array of float values in big-endian format (not as a string).

The question is how can i convert this data into an array of float numbers?

the code:

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(hostIP)
tn.read_until("connected")
tn.write("getData\r\n")
data = tn.read_until("\r\n")
print data
```

When i execute this script from terminal i get some binary "garbage"

> ```
> ²\f²▒▒²▒V²▒²▒
>   ³▒▒³u▒³:v³▒>³;>²W▒²O^²Xf²▒▒±▒▒²P▒²▒j²▒²▒³Pv³▒▒²▒n²:Z²▒±▒F±▒±7▒±@▒±t^±▒▒±▒▒²5:±▒"±▒~±ю±±*±▒°▒▒°{n°a▒°▒:°Q▒°[°cj°0▒¯▒▒¯▒▒r¯ޒ°▒°▒¯▒▒¯a▒¯▒°E▒°▒r°q*¯▒¯▒
> ```

If i do the same from python shell i get the \xc2\xb2\xdd\x0f\xc2... values

Comment: Do you know how many floats you will get? `struct.unpack` should be able to turn the binary data into a tuple of values. There's probably a way to do it with `numpy` as well.

Comment: Could you paste your code here?And maybe you need use numpy or pandas to do it.

Comment: @Blckknght I dont know the number of floats i get. When i try struct.unpack('d',data) i get struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know in advance the number of elements in the array, or somehow infer the count, ie by counting the number of bytes and then dividing by the float size. You then use the struct module to unpack the binary data.

```
if (len(data) % 8) > 0:
    assert "Data length not a multiple of 8"
L = []
for i in range(0, len(data), 8):
    L.append(struct.unpack('>d', data[i:i+8]))
```

Comment: This is what i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./telnet.py", line 27, in <module>
    if (data % 8) > 0:
ValueError: unsupported format character '▒' (0xfffffff2) at index 283

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be `len(data) % 8`.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @vz0 answer, there is also `struct.iter_unpack()` that:

> Iteratively unpack from the buffer buffer according to the format string format.
> [read the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack)

So we can convert without any trouble:

```
import struct
import numpy as np

# Choose operators from https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings
Byte_Order = '<' # little-endian
Format_Characters = 'f' # float (4 bytes)

data_format = Byte_Order + Format_Characters

r = np.array(list(struct.iter_unpack(data_format, data)), dtype=float)
```